# Using colon (':') to access elements in an array in C++ (in Rcpp)

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to run the following code. Frankly I know C++ only little but I want to get the following function run. Can you help me run this silly example?

```
cppFunction(
  'NumericVector abc(int x, int x_end, NumericVector y)
  {
    NumericVector z;
    int x1 = x + x_end;
    z = y[x:x1];
    return(z);  
   }'
)

abc(3,c(0,1,10,100,1000,10000))
```

I see this ...

*error: expected ']' before ':' token*

**Update**
Sorry I forgot to mention that I need to generate a sequence of numbers from `x` to `x1`. The function `IntegerVector::create` only creates a variable with only `x` and `x1` not `x` though `x1`. The example I gave was trivial. I updated the example now. I need to do in **C++** what `seq()` does in **R**

**Solution based on the answer below (@SleuthEye)**

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  'NumericVector abc(int x, int x_end, NumericVector y)
  {
  NumericVector z;
  Range idx(x,x_end);
  z = y[idx];
  return(z);  
  }'
)

abc(3,5,c(0,1,10,100,1000,10000))
[1]   100  1000 10000
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with rcpp, but [this link](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/) suggests it could be done with something like `IntegerVector idx = IntegerVector::create(x,x1); z = y[idx];`

Comment: This is also an intresting read: [A slice of Python in C++ by Eric Niebler](http://ericniebler.com/2014/12/07/a-slice-of-python-in-c/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code argument to `Rcpp`'s `cppFunction` must include valid C++ code. The library tries to make as seamless as possible, but is still restricted to the syntax of C++. More specifically, C++ does not have a range operator (`:`) and correspondingly the C++ compiler tells you that the indexing expression must be a valid index (enclosed within `[]`, without the `:`). The type of the index could be an `int` or `IntegerVector`, but it cannot contain the `:` character.

As suggesting in [Rcpp subsetting article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/), you may however create a vector which represent the desired `(x,x+1)` range which you can then use to index `NumericVector` variables as such:

```
IntegerVector idx = IntegerVector::create(x, x+1);
z = y[idx];
```

More generally, you can use a [`Range`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/classRcpp_1_1Range.html) in a similar fashion:

```
Range idx(x, x1);
z = y[idx];
```

Comment: Sorry @SleuthEye, I need to generate a sequence from `x` to `x1` (`x1` will not necessarily be `x+1`. Any way to do in C++.