# Sequence of Integers in Rcpp

Tags: r, sequence, rcpp

I want to create a sequence of integer numbers for indexing within a matrix. The `R` pendant would be:

```
indexRow <- max(0,1):min(2,12)
matrix1[indexRow, ]
```

This is what i have tried in `Rcpp` to create the sequence of integers:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test(NumericVector x) {
  IntegerVector indexRow = Rcpp::seq_along(max(0, 1), min(1, 12));
}
```

However I get the Error message:

```
no matching function for call to 'seq_along(const int&, const int&)'
```

How can I create a sequence of integers in Rcpp?

Comment: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063951/using-colon-to-access-elements-in-an-array-in-c-in-rcpp) could be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible Rcpp implementation :

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(plugins='cpp11','NumericVector myseq(int &first, int &last) {
NumericVector y(abs(last - first) + 1);
if (first < last) 
   std::iota(y.begin(), y.end(), first);
else {
   std::iota(y.begin(), y.end(), last);
   std::reverse(y.begin(), y.end());
 }
return y;
}')
#> myseq(max(0,1), min(13,17))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

This code generates a function `myseq` which takes two arguments: The first and the last number in an integer series. It is similar to R's `seq` function called with two integer arguments `seq(first, last)`.

A documentation on the C++11 function `std::iota` is given [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: Rcpp has a seq function as well FWIW.

Comment: Oh! Good to know. Thank you @nrussell . So the languages are sort of gradually "merging" within Rcpp... There is no seq function in the C++ standard that I know of.

Comment: Yes the [sugar functions](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions) in Rcpp more or less correspond to their R counterparts, so I think merging is a good way to put it.

Answer (score 4):

`seq_along` takes in a vector, what you want to use is `seq` combined with `min` and `max`, both take vectors. `seq` returns an `IntegerVector`. Here is an example.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector test(IntegerVector a, IntegerVector b) {
  IntegerVector vec =  seq(max(a), min(b));
 return vec;
}
```

In `R` you use

```
> test(c(0,1), c(2,12))
[1] 1 2
```